# Convert microseconds time stamp epoch to date-time in sql

Tags: sql, datetime, quartz.net

I am using Quartz.net and in sql it saves NEXT_FIRE_TIME column as bigint.
For example: 635834196000000000.

I need to convert this to human readable date time.
I tried following solution but I am getting

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

error. Am I missing something?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ConvertToDateTime] (@Datetime BIGINT)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS BEGIN DECLARE @Return datetime
SELECT @return = dateadd(s,@Datetime/1000000,'1970-01-01')
RETURN @return END
```

Comment: probably you need to `cast (@Datetime/1000000 as integer)` or something like that

Comment: Your code works when I try it with reasonable values.  Are you sure the problem is in this function?